# how to implement a pop up confirmation window without javascript

Tags: java

I Want to implement a confirmation pop up having ok and cancel button without javascript ,how can i do so in java

Comment: Can I confirm that you are referring to a web application?

Comment: why are you so afraid of javascript?

Comment: yes i am referring to a web application on mobile so i cant use javascript because normally phones does not support .js functionality

Comment: can any one help me out,since its a mobile based wap app

Comment: @Sarah- it depends what you're trying to do, who your target audience is. JavaScript support is getting better in mobile and in my experience, is generally usable in a lot of the smartphone devices. So, there is a limited choice of what you can without JavaScript, therefore it may be a good to rethink other areas of your current solution/idea

Comment: Is she talking about a J2ME application? :)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer- you can't. The ability to close a window (which is, I assume what you want the OK and/or Cancel buttons to do) is a javascript feature.

If you don't care about closing the window, you can simply have a link in your web page that points to target="_blank" to open a new window.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to have a modal dialog box without having some form of client side script. The nearest experience that you would be able to achieve is to redirect you application to a confirm/cancel screen when performing some action, but this may become extremely annoying for more trivial decisions

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement it in JavaScript.
2. Check if JavaScript is enabled, if not, popup as message asking user to enable it.